# Null point exception on set spring JPA relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have already seen topics with this question, but they did not help me. Maybe I didn't see something.
Below I attach the code and the error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 36, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;


    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<User> userSet =  new HashSet<>();

}
```

AND user

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 36, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dep_id", nullable = true)
    private Department department;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "device_devices",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "device_id"))
    Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and service

```
@Override
public List<DepartmentDto> getAllDepartment() {
    List<Department> all = departmentRepository.findAll();
    return all.stream().map(mapper::toDepartmentDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}


@Override
public UUID createDepartment(DepartmentDto departmentDto) {
    Department entity = mapper.DtoToDepartment(departmentDto);
    return departmentRepository.save(entity).getId();
}

@Override
public void deleteDepartment(UUID id) {
    departmentRepository.deleteById(id);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void addUserToDepartment(UUID departmentId,UUID userId){
    Department department = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId).orElseThrow(DepartmentNotFoundException::new);
    User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
    department.getUserSet().add(user); // ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    user.setDepartment(department);
}
```

I think I did something wrong. I tried writing **Cascade.ALL** but it didn't help me. I don't think I fully understand the concept of a link collection yet. I don't like that in my code, I add the user to the department, and then I add the department to the user. Probably it can be done in one action.

Task.
I want to make a department and 2 functions. Add a user to the department and remove users from the department. in such a way that the contempt of the users from the department the user himself was not removed.

I will be glad to hear your comments

Comment: A side note: Don't use `@Data` for entities. The definition of an entity is an object that has an identity distinct from its current values, and `@Data` breaks identity expectations. Use `@Getter @Setter` instead.

Comment: @WBLord I would suggest you to move your fields initialization like this `Set<User> userSet =  new HashSet<>()` to the no-args entity constructor.

Comment: I don't think this is the most beautiful way out

Comment: may i see "mapper.DtoToDepartment" method ? do you  use Department.builder()....build() ?

Answer (score 1):

if you use @Builder annotation on top of the class
and you want to set default value for a field,
you must put annotation @Builder.Default on top of field

```
@Builder.Default
Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<>();
```

otherwise devices will always be NULL when the builder builds the object